# App using TKinterModernThemes made with PyInstaller gives the error "invalid command name "set_theme""

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, ttk

I've been trying to make an app using tkinter, TKinterModernThemes, and turn it into an executable with PyInstaller, and I've had no luck. Every time I try to use any kind of module using ttk themes, I run into some sort of error. I decided to settle on using the TKinterModernThemes module. Making an exe using PyInstaller gives me the following error:

```
 File "TKinterModernThemes\__init__.py", line 66, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "set_theme"
```

I've tried including both tkinter and TKinterModernThemes as a hidden import in PyInstaller, trying with and without --onefile, and using Nuitka instead (same error). Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: In order to be helpful, more information needs to be included in your question, for example, the directory structure, an example of the code you are attempting to compile, the command you are entering into your terminal, the spec file output from pyinstaller, any error messages received.

Comment: Does it run before compiling with PyInstaller? I have installed[TKinterModernThemes](https://github.com/RobertJN64/TKinterModernThemes) with pip and tried to run one of the examples and I got `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "set_theme"` too.

Comment: After looking in the code, it seems that I got the error because the module failed to load the tcl module corresponding to the theme, hence the failure of the set_theme command which is defined in that module. The problem is the way the path is defined in `ThemedTKinterFrame.__init__` (in `TKinterModernThemes/__init__.py`), I had to add `os.path.abspath(...)` around the path line 66.

Answer (score 0):

I changed manually my path here `ThemedTKinterFrame.__init__`, at line 64 like this

```
self.root.tk.call("source", "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TKinterModernThemes/themes/" + theme.lower() + "/" + theme.lower() + ".tcl")
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --collect-data TKinterModernThemes --collect-data PIL .\FILENAME.py

SAVED MY LIFE!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed in version 1.9.0 - the issue was the '/../' that I had in the library to move up a directory - the os.path.abspath handles this better.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).